# Como agrupar valores do BD?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou refazendo esta pergunta de forma mais clara.
Estou com o seguinte desafio;
Tenho um BD que contém 16 campos de informações, este BD guarda apostas efetuadas em um sistema, pra posteriormente poder processar o resultado e pagamento do bilhete do cliente.
Na parte de administração, o ADM tem uma área onde é possível colocar os resultados do jogos que foram efetuados pelo cliente, quando o cliente efetua uma aposta, é armazenado o nome do time, o tipo de aposta, e o confronto.
Por exemplo, tem um jogo de Vasco e Flamengo, você aposta que o Vasco vai fazer 2 gols no segundo tempo, no BD eu armazeno estas informações da seguinte maneira:

***Nome do time: Vasco.***

***Tipo de aposta: +2.***

***Confronto: Vasco x Flamengo.***

Na parte administrativa, o ADM tem que conferir todos os jogos que estão no BD, só que vários clientes faz o mesmo tipo de aposta, ou seja, terei no BD 15,20 registros repetidos, com o mesmo ***Nome do time***, mesmo ***Tipo de aposta*** e mesmo ***Confronto***.

O Administrador, faz as conferência dos jogos, por um *`select`*, eu imprimo todos os registros do BD em uma, a select tem 3 opções, *"ganhou, perdeu, cancelado"*. e pela ID do registro daquele confronto, eu consigo atualizar o resultado no BD.

Mas o problema, é que tem muitos resultados repetidos, e fica complicado para o administrador colocar o mesmo resultado em vários jogos iguais, exemplo:
[image: Print do sistema com jogos repetidos]

O Que eu quero, é agrupar estes jogos, baseado no mesmo confronto,Condição aposta e Aposta, e o resultado que o administrador colocar no select, valha para todos do mesmo grupo, sem que seja preciso colocar o mesmo resultado várias vezes.
Em `PHP` eu consigo agrupar no `sql`:

```
$conexao->prepare('SELECT time_apostado,tipojogo,tipoaposta,codigo  FROM bilhetes_temp WHERE codigo GROUP BY time_apostado,tipojogo,tipoaposta');
```

Mas não faço a mínima de ideia de como mostrar apenas 1 resultado para o admin, e fazer com que o o resultado da select que ele colocar, valha para todos os outros que são iguais.

Espero não ter sido longo na explicação, não tinha como resumi tal pergunta rs.
Então, alguém me dar uma ideia de como eu agrupo esses resultados no `PHP` ou também no `JasvaScript`?

Comment: complicado entender... teria que reler umas 10 ou 20 vezes e isso consome muito tempo.. seja mais objetivo e claro.. e também procure escrever de forma mais organizada, com uma boa gramática também ajuda  a outros lerem e interpretarem o seu texto. Confesso que eu li as primeiras palavras e já deu uma confusão mental e daí pra frente deu preguiça de ler o restante.. imagino que outros sintam o mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dizes na pergunta que conheces a função GROUP BY e que sabes agrupar por um valor. Podes usar esta função para agrupar pelas três colunas, deste modo, removendo os resultados duplicados.

Isto pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT Time, TipoDeJogo, DataDoJogo
FROM TABELA_JOGOS
GROUP BY Time, TipoDeJogo, DataDoJogo
ORDER BY Time, TipoDeJogo, DataDoJogo
```

Comment: Bruno, muito obrigado, tentei algo parecido mas não funcionou, do seu modo funcionou direitinho.